# Trying to understand the sort utilty in linux

Tags: linux, sorting, csv, gnu-sort

I have a file named a.csv. which contains

```
100008,3
10000,3
100010,5
100010,4
10001,6
100021,7
```

After running this command `sort -k1 -d -t "," a.csv`

The result is

```
10000,3
100008,3
100010,4
100010,5
10001,6
100021,7
```

Which is unexpected because `10001 should come first than 100010`

Trying to understand why this happened from long time. but couldn't get any answers.

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the other responses have assumed this is a numeric sort vs dictionary sort problem.  It isn't, as even sorting alphabetically the output given in the question is incorrect.

### The answer

To get the correct sorting, you need to change `-k1` to `-k1,1`:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -d -t "," a.csv
10000,3
100008,3
10001,6
100010,4
100010,5
100021,7
```

### The reason

The `-k` option takes two numbers, the start and end fields to sort (i.e. `-ks,e` where `s` is the start and `e` is the end).  By default, the end field is the end of the line.  Hence, `-k1` is the same as not giving the `-k` option at all.  To show this, compare:

```
$ printf "1,a,1\n2,aa,2\n" | sort -k2 -t,
1,a,1
2,aa,2
```

with:

```
$ printf "1~a~1\n2~aa~2\n" | sort -k2 -t~
2~aa~2
1~a~1
```

The first sorts `a,1` before `aa,2`, while the second sorts `aa~2` before `a~1` since, in ASCII, `,` < `a` < `~`.

To get the desired behaviour, therefore, we need to sort *only* one field.  In your case, that means using 1 as both the start and end field, so you specify `-k1,1`.  If you try the two examples above with `-k2,2` instead of `-k2`, you'll find you get the same (correct) ordering in both cases.

Many thanks to Eric and Assaf from the coreutils mailing list for pointing this out.

Comment: It seems that if you set the locale to C then it works.  I've just updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks to Eric and Assaf on the coreutils mailing list, I've got to the bottom of this.  I've updated the answer with the correct conclusion now.

Answer (score 2):

You have not found a bug in sort.  Your usage bug is that you used '-k1' ("set the key to the first field through the end of the line") instead of '-k1,1' ("set the key to use only the first field").  If you use GNU sort, the --debug option will show you the difference.  The delimiter is included in the key as long as the key extends beyond a single field.

Answer (score 0):

It sorts alphabetically, not numerically, so "," is before "0", i.e. more like a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The `-d` option is for `--dictionary-order`:

> -d, --dictionary-order
>       consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters

But I think you want to use `-n` (`--numeric-sort`) instead:

> -n, --numeric-sort
>       compare according to string numerical value

So, change your command to look like this:

```
sort -k1 -n -t "," a.csv
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html

Answer (score 0):

The sort is alphabetical, not numerical. Replace -d by -n in your option list to sort numerically.